# Guess the formula of a matrix

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, induction

[image: pic] 
Given a matrix $A$ of size $2\times2$ . $A^2$, $A^3$,$A^4$,and $A^5$ are calculated as seen above.
It is required that : 
Based on your calculation above, Guess a formula for $A^{2n}$ and $A^{2n+1}$(Prove)

I tried some formulas but all are non sense

Comment: picture updated

Comment: The matrix powers given are incorrect.

Comment: $A^2$ is the identity matrix, so the problem is nonsensical.

Comment: fixed A^3 I had a mistake

Comment: @MathDisease No, also $A^2$ is incorrect.

Comment: matrices answers fixed , why down-vote ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's straightforward to calculate (and see) that $A^2 = I$.

Then, $A^{2n}=(A^2)^n = I^n = I,$ and $A^{2n+1} = A^{2n}A = IA = A.$

Comment: fixed the matrices answers